# Getting Current Controller ID in Yii

Tags: php, templates, yii, yii-components

I want to get the current controller name that handles the current action.
but the in my case **I will look for the current controller in my main.php in my layout files**.

this is my small view of my directory structure to give you an idea where is my layout files and the file where i will put my codes in searching of my controller name

> - /protected
> - /themes
>
>   - /mylayout
>
>     - /layouts
>
>       - **main.php**
>       - column1.php
>       - column2.php
>     - /site
>
>       - index.php

Is this possible? im trying the following codes but i failed to get my current controller name...

```
echo Yii::app()->controller->getId;
echo Yii:app()->getController->id;
echo Yii:app()->controller->uniqueID;
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<?php echo $this->getUniqueId();?>`

this will show current controller

Answer (score 25):

Like this

```
Yii::app()->controller->id
```

or

```
Yii::app()->getController()->getId()
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#getController-detail

Comment: I prefer your answer, because your answer works any where, views, widgets, extensions, etc. E.G. in case of calling CGridView, $this refers to it's widgets and $this->id results in widget name and not controller name.

Answer (score 13):

Controller Id :

```
$this->id
```

Here $this refers to controller.

And
For getting action id :

```
$this->action->id
```

Comment: thanks for help but. I will look for the current controller in my main.php in my layout files... is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually required to use the static function. Whenever in a view( or template) you can use `echo $this->getUniqueId();` to get the unique controller ID.

Answer (score 1):

Yii2:

`Yii::$app->controller->id`

(Documentation: [Application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html) and [Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html))