# How to get controller name inside CGridView?

Tags: php, gridview, yii

In views controller name can be achieved by **$this->id**, but in CGridView $this->id evaluation results in another name (may be gridview widget name). **(1)** How can I get controller name in cgridview?

> Also I tried to define a variable ($thisCtl = $this->id) before calling CGridview. Although $thisCtl has the controller name, in CGridview evaluation process it is not defined. **(2)** Is there any way to pass a parameter to CGridView?

```
<?php 
$thisCtl = $this->id;
$data = $model->search(); 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id'=>'insurance-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'registeration_date',
        'modification_date',
        array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'), 
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn', 
            'viewButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("$thisCtl/view", array("id"=>$data["id"]))', 
            'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("$this->id/update", array("id"=>$data["id"]))', 
        ),
    ),
));
```

?>

Comment: have you tried `Yii::app()->id`

Comment: I tried, it has an strange value!

Comment: Have you try this `'Yii::app()->createUrl("'.$this->id.'/update", array("id"=>$data["id"]))'`

Comment: I tried, $this in CGridView refers to it's widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you wish to use the controller value within the column values, you can do the following to get the controller name:

```
$this->grid->controller->id
```

As you are within a [TbButtonColumn](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/blob/master/widgets/TbButtonColumn.php), you can access the [grid](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#grid-detail) property (since TbButtonColumn extends from [CButtonColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn) which in turn extends from [CGridColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn)) to access the [TbExtendsGridView](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/blob/master/widgets/TbExtendedGridView.php) (which ultimately extends from [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)) where you in turn access the [controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#controller-detail) property of the grid (which is defined by the widget parent), and finally the get [id](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#id-detail) of the controller.

Then, assuming all your other code is correct, you would specify your gridview like so:

```
<?php 
$data = $model->search(); 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id'=>'insurance-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'registeration_date',
        'modification_date',
        array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'), 
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn', 
            'viewButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl($this->grid->controller->id."/view", array("id"=>$data["id"]))', 
            'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl($this->grid->controller->id."/update", array("id"=>$data["id"]))', 
        ),
    ),
));
```

I haven't used any of the `Tb` extensions myself, by so long as they did not alter the built in behavior of the objects they extended, the above should work as desired.

Comment: I tried your solution: Recoverable error

Object of class TbExtendedGridView could not be converted to string

Comment: Hmm, it may have been an issue with the object chaining within the eval'd double quotes. Using `eval()` can be tricky sometimes. See if it works with the edit I just made.

Comment: it's OK, 1- what was your edit on your answer? 2- I prefer your answer more, because it's correct way of getting controller name from gridView while my answer is a remedy!

Comment: @HPM I changed `->createUrl("$this->grid->controller->id/update",` to `->createUrl($this->grid->controller->id."/update",)` for both the urls. Chaining objects within double quotes is what I suspect the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that $this in CGridView refers to it's widget. So we should use a global function to get current controller name:

> Yii::app()->getController()->getId();

the code should look like:

```
<?php 
$thisCtl = $this->id;
$data = $model->search(); 
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id'=>'insurance-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'registeration_date',
        'modification_date',
        array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'), 
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn', 
            'viewButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("'.Yii::app()->getController()->getId().'/view", array("id"=>$data["id"]))', 
            'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("'.Yii::app()->getController()->getId().'/update", array("id"=>$data["id"]))', 
        ),
    ),
));
```

?>

Thanks to this post [Getting Current Controller ID in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582237/getting-current-controller-id-in-yii)