# in yii how to get controller and action name ? showing error while calling from

Tags: php, yii

i have tried to access current controller and action name using following code , it works for the controller but failing in case of action name (code location: protected/components/controller.php)

```
class Controller extends CController
{

    public $layout='//layouts/column1';

    public $menu=array();

    public $breadcrumbs=array();
        public function init()
        {
           echo Yii::app()->controller->id; // working fine
          echo Yii::app()->controller->action->id; exit; // showing error ![enter image description here][1]

        }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582237/getting-current-controller-id-in-yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
protected function beforeAction($event) {
    echo Yii::app()->controller->id;
    echo Yii::app()->controller->action->id;
    exit;
}
```

rather than

```
public function init() {
    echo Yii::app()->controller->id;
    echo Yii::app()->controller->action->id;
    exit;
}
```

In `init()` runs when the controller is initialized, but the action is not known yet and so the object does not have the `action` property associated with it.